# 2d vector modify with iterator

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++20

I have a 2d matrix using `vector` library. And I wanted to iterate over the `Matrix` more conveniently, so I created an `MatrixIterator` class.

**Matrix.cpp**

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class MatrixIterator;

template <class T>
class Matrix
{
    friend class MatrixIterator<T>;

private:
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> m;
    unsigned rows_;
    unsigned cols_;

    Matrix<T>(unsigned rows, unsigned cols);

    MatrixIterator<T> iterator() const
    {
        return {*this};
    }

    MatrixIterator<T> begin() const
    {
        return {*this};
    }

    MatrixIterator<T> end() const
    {
        return {*this, rows_, 0};
    }
}


template <class T>
class MatrixIterator
{
private:
    Matrix<T> matrix_;
    unsigned row_;
    unsigned col_;

public:
    MatrixIterator<T>(Matrix<T> m) : matrix_(m), row_(0), col_(0) {};
    MatrixIterator<T>(Matrix<T> m, unsigned row, unsigned col) : matrix_(m), row_(row), col_(col) {};

    MatrixIterator<T> begin() const
    {
        return {matrix_};
    }

    MatrixIterator<T> end() const
    {
        return {matrix_, matrix_.rows_, 0};
    }

    void inc()
    {
        if(++col_ >= matrix_.cols_)
        {
            row_++;
            col_ = 0;
        }
    }

    MatrixIterator<T>& operator++()
    {
        inc();
        return *this;
    }

    MatrixIterator<T> operator++(int)
    {
        inc();
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator!=(const MatrixIterator<T> &rhs) const
    {
        return (row_ != rhs.row_) || (col_ != rhs.col_);
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return matrix_.m[row_][col_];
    }
};


template <class T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned cols)
    : rows_(rows), cols_(cols)
{

    m.resize(cols);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    {
        m[i].resize(rows);
        fill(m[i].begin(), m[i].end(), T());
    }
}
```

In the following code, when I try to manipulate value using iterator, it does not change the value.
I tried returning the values as pointers from `operator*` but it did not work either. I saw no errors. What is wrong and how can I solve this?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Matrix.cpp"
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    Matrix<int> m = Matrix<int>{3,3};
    for(auto x: m.iterator())
        x = 10;
    for(auto x: m.iterator())
        std::cout << x << " ";
    // outputs 0 0 0 ~
}
```

Compiled with `g++ main.cpp -std=c++20 -g -o main && main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a reference in the iterator class, other than hold a copy of it (iterator is just a view of the data).

```cpp
template <class T>
class MatrixIterator {
 private:
  Matrix<T>& matrix_;
  unsigned row_;
  unsigned col_;

 public:
  MatrixIterator<T>(Matrix<T>& m) : MatrixIterator<T>(m, 0, 0) {}
  MatrixIterator<T>(Matrix<T>& m, unsigned row, unsigned col)
      : matrix_(m), row_(row), col_(col) {}
};
```

And you also need to non-const `begin` and `end` for your matrix, nonconst version iterator can be used to change the underlying value. The function `iterator()` can be removed here, since it's not common to have this in c++ code.

```cpp
  MatrixIterator<T> begin() const { return {*this}; }
  MatrixIterator<T> begin() { return {*this}; }

  MatrixIterator<T> end() const { return {*this, rows_, 0}; }
  MatrixIterator<T> end() { return {*this, rows_, 0}; }
```

To change to the value with an iterator, you need a reference other than changing the copied value in your main function. It's not necessary to explicitly call the `iterator` here, the compiler will [do it for you](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

```cpp
int main() {
  Matrix<int> m = Matrix<int>{3, 3};
  for (auto& x : m) x = 10;
  for (auto x : m) std::cout << x << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9bKvE7rdG).

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over *values*, not references when attempting to change the matrix values. Instead, try

```
for (auto& x : m.iterator())
```